# How to convert array like this ["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019", "Angle,Darma,11242019"] to Array of hash Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, hash, each

How to convert array:

```
["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019", "Angle,Darma,11242019"]
```

to Array of hash like this using Ruby :

```
[
  { :name => "John Doe", :number => 11222019 },
  { :name => "Mark King", :number => 11232019 },
  { :name => "Angle Darma", :number => 11242019 },
]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply as below,

```
array.map { |x| [:name, :number].zip(x.sub(',', ' ').split(',')).to_h }

# => [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>11222019}, {:name=>"Mark King", :number=>11232019}, {:name=>"Angle Darma", :number=>11242019}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works well in ruby versions 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 . Saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

Option using Ruby 2.6.1 [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-then):

```
ary = ["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019", "Angle,Darma,11242019"]

ary.map { |s| s.split(',').then{ |a| {name: a.first(2).join(' ') , number: a.last.to_i } } }
```

For Ruby 2.5.2 [Object#yield_self](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Object.html#method-i-yield_self):

```
ary.map { |s| s.split(',').yield_self{ |a| {name: a.first(2).join(' ') , number: a.last.to_i } } }
```

Both returning:

```
#=> [{:name=>"John Doe", :number=>11222019}, {:name=>"Mark King", :number=>11232019}, {:name=>"Angle Darma", :number=>11242019}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works well in ruby versions 2.5, 2.6

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019",
       "Angle,Darma,11242019"]

arr.map do |s|
  {name: s[/.+(?=,)/].tr(',',' '), number: s[/\d+/].to_i}
end
  #=> [{:name=>"John Doe",    :number=>11222019},
  #    {:name=>"Mark King",   :number=>11232019},
  #    {:name=>"Angle Darma", :number=>11242019}]
```

The steps are as follows. [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) passes the first element of `arr` to the block and the block variable `s` is set equal to its value:

```
s = arr.first
  #=> "John,Doe,11222019"
```

The block calculations are then performed:

```
a = s[/.+(?=,)/]
  #=> "John,Doe"
```

This uses the method [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html) with the regular expression `/.+(?=,)/`. `(?=,)` is a *positive lookahead* that requires the match to be followed immediately by a comma. Because matches are by default *greedy* the lookahead matches the last comma in `s`.

```
b = a.tr(',',' ')
  #=> "John Doe"
```

This uses the method [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-tr). Alternatively, `a.sub(',',' ')` could be used.

```
c = s[/\d+/]
  #=> "11222019" 
d = c.to_i
  #=> 11222019
```

The block then returns:

```
{ name: c, number: d }
  #=> {:name=>"11222019", :number=>11222019}
```

which is the object to which `s` is mapped. The remaining two values of `arr` are passed to the block and similar calculations are performed.

Answer (score 0):

a = ["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019", "Angle,Darma,11242019"]

Something like this

```
a.map do |f|
  f = f.split(',')
  { name: "#{f[0]} #{f[1]}", number: f[2].to_i }
end
```

Comment: or `a, b, c = f.split(',')` and `{ name: "#{a} #{b}", number: c.to_i }`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["John,Doe,11222019", "Mark,King,11232019", "Angle,Darma,11242019"]

arr.map do |item|
  chunks = item.split(",")
  {name: chunks[0...-1].join(" "), number: chunks[-1]}
end
```

Indexing by [0...-1] allows you to have variable number of items in the name part (middle name, or 2 piece last names) which is pretty common.

Comment: Thank you. Working well!